# When multiple users are viewing a record and 1 person updates the record, how to notify other the record is updated?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

In my Project Management app I want to solve the issue of multiple users viewing the same Task record and 1 or more of them updating some of the Tasks Data while the others are viewing it.

---

**Here is a scenario...**

**User #1** views **Task #1** and **User #2** views **Task #1**

Now **User #2** updates the **Task #1 Description**

**User #1** is now viewing the Task record but his view shows a different out-dated **Description** since **User #2** had just updated it!  Even worse he may want to edit the description himself which would completely over-write **User #2's** Description update.

---

That is 1 example of the issue.  Just add more users and the issue multiplies!

Ideally I would use something like Sockets or a service like Pusher.com to update the data for all users as soon as an update by any user is made.  However this project is going to be on hundreds of servers and has limited capabilities as far as server requirements so sockets and even a service like Pusher are out of the question!

Another idea for a solution is based on what Twitter does.  If you view a persons Twitter page and they make a new post while you have there page loaded.  It will show a notification message DIV to tell you there are X number of new posts and give you a link to click to reload the stream of posts with the latest posts.

[image]

I believe a similar approach could work for my project.  If a user makes an update to any Task data while other users are viewing that Task record.  It would show a Notification message on the Task modal window telling the user that the Task data has been updated and that they should reload the Task.

To make this work I know there will need to be some AJAX request made at some interval.

That AJAX request would then need to compare the timestamp of the last update made on the Task record and compare it with the time the user viewing the Task record started viewing it or since they last reloaded the task.

I feel like my logic is missing a piece of the puzzle though?  Is this all correct or am I missing something?

Can someone explain how I can do this or tell me if what I have in mind is right?

I know that in short I simply need to determine if the Task last modified Timestamp is AFTER the other user started viewing the Task.  At some point though I feel  the users time should be updated too?

**UPDATE**

I completely forgot that Stack Overflow does this exact task on questions and answers!  When you view a page on SO and a Answer is updated it will show a notification message telling you to reload the answer and provide a link to reload it.  That is what I want to do!

**StackOverflow uses Web Sockets to do this but in my app which is a plugin to be used on many different server configurations, I cannot use Sockets.  I am trying to achieve similar result with AJAX.  Even if it's an AJAX request made every 30 seconds to get the task modified Time and compare it to another to determine if user should reload task data would work in my case**

[image]

Comment: You can start with http://www.dev-metal.com/architecture-stackoverflow/ and especially Update #3 and http://highscalability.com/stack-overflow-architecture and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network are a few related links I found. There are more but that should get you started. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, from what I can gather they are doing it using Web sockets here which makes sense as that the best route however in my case do to the users who will use my app I am limited and cannot use sockets so I think I should be able to achieve the same result with an AJAX polling technique

Comment: You're welcome Jason. I'm thinking the same thing as you. However, I'm not well-versed enough in that field to further comment (I know some, but not as other members on Stack), but they could also be using both methods. You may be able to get away with just using an AJAX polling technique.

Comment: @Fred-ii- same here.  I know 5-6 years ago the AJAX method was used everywhere as it was all we had back then!  So I know it's possible.  It has drawbacks but in my case it is my best option as my app is a plugin to be installed on many server configurations.  It is inside of SugarCRM so at least it is private traffic for most users within a business who will use it so even an AJAX request made every 15-30 seconds to compare 2 timestamps will do the trick I believe.  If it was my choice I would use Pusher.com and be done in 5 minutes!  Hoping for others to join in here though =)

Comment: @JasonDavis Did you end up using a basic AJAX polling technique?

Comment: @kcbeard I haven't implemented a solution yet I am just researching for when I do it.  I will likely use a combination in my app/plugin to allow user to user service like Pusher.coim for live socket updates and as a fallback use the AJAX polling a script every 30 seconds or so

Comment: @JasonDavis lightweight polling can be extremely efficient. I use a technique using a cached object for comparison. It polls for a its object every 15 seconds. The object has 6 sub objects and around 50 properties. Though my situation is different it is for a web app instead of a plugin. Also I am using angular makes life easy. But polling was a solid solution for us.

Comment: @kcbeard my app is a plugin for sugarCRM however its a full blown appm projects, tasks, comments, documents, forums, gantts charts, kanban boards, users, ACL, settings, and more so its a big app but packages as a plugin to install into sugarcrm.  The plus side is that sugarcrm is used by employees of companies so overall the traffic is low in most cases so I do think polling would work fine.  On the other hand I have used polling on large social network app before which had 100s of active users a second and in that case it wasn't a great idea. Glad it worked for you I think ill give it a go

Comment: here you can find most of the technologies you can use  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet you should take a look at long polling if all you can use are AJAX calls

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad, but you are basically describing a Pub/Sub.

#### Idea

Whenever a user enters your site, he gets a token to identify them.

If he accesses a task, he subscribes to that task, which means that any modification on it would be alerted to him.

He polls the server to check if there is any alert to him.

#### Implementation

Regarding implementation, you can set-up a list with each user's subscriptions.
Using your example:

User1 subscribes to (Task1, Task2)

User2 subscribes to (Task1)

With each subscription, you keep some value that represents the last state the user has about that topic (e.g, the last modification timestamp).

The user polls your application every n seconds. Whenever the request reaches your application, you check the user's subscriptions, and check if the timestamp has changed (if they have the latest). If so, you update the last state that the user has and retrieves him the new values for the tasks that changed.

#### Things to consider

This list of subscriptions will be constantly accessed, so becareful where you are going to store it. If in memory, consider that you will need to share it across the different instances (if you are load balancing). You can use Redis, or something like that.

You do not need to go to your database everytime you need to retrieve data. If someone is subscribing to it, keep it on a cache.

Answer (score 1):

The concept and idea is fairly trivial, and the implementation shouldn't be any more difficult. You need a **Last Updated** timestamp for each task as you say, as well as a **Last Update** timestamp on the client if you go with the described approach. Generally, when a **User** is viewing a **Task**, you'd want to (on the client side, Javascript):

1. Query the server for the **Last Updated** timestamp of the **Task** being viewed with AJAX.
2. If the **Last Updated** timestamp of the **Task** being viewed is greater (newer) than the **Last Update** timestamp on the client goto step 5.
3. Wait (asynchronously) n seconds.
4. Goto step 1.
5. Notify **User** that the **Task** being viewed has been updated.
6. End (since it is already known to the client that the **Task** has been updated, there is no need to keep polling whether it's been updated or not).

One approach could be simply creating an asynchronous interval using [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) that would be cleared once it has been determined an update occurred, and the user is shown a message afterwards.

```
var lastUpdate = Date.now();
var intervalDuration = 30000; // 30 seconds
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ...
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (...) { // if the Task's Last Updated timestamp is newer than lastUpdate
            clearInterval(interval);
            // show message to user that the Task has been updated
        }
    };
}, intervalDuration);
```

I can imagine in a significantly massive system this approach could be easily inadequate, but for non-enterprise grade solutions or for follow-up UI improvements this can be a quick, cheap, and spectacular solution.

Of course there are potentially more robust and flexible alternatives to this: [long-polling or websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet).